# "List index out of range" con lista ingresada por teclado

Tags: python, python-3.x

Al ejecutar mi script en Python, ¿por qué me sale el error:

> List index out of range

aunque en la lista el índice exista? Aquí está mi código:

```
a=[input()]
b=input()
c=int(input())

d=[a[0], a[2]]
print(d)
```

Al ejecutarlo, este es el error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                              
  File "lista.py", line 6, in <module>                                          
    d=[a[0], a[2]]                                                              
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Luego, modifiqué mi código así:

```
a=list(input())
b=str(input())
c=int(input())

new_a = [b, a[1], a[2], c]
print(new_a)
```

Al imprimir, no me identifica los elementos de `a` como lista, entonces al introducir por ejemplo:

```
carro, silla, mesa
pelota
56
```

El programa me da como resultado:

```
['pelota', 'a', 'r', 56]
```

Quiero que en la posición [1] y [2] de la nueva lista vaya la [1] y [2] de la lista anterior, en qué fallo?

Comment: No sé qué pretendes exactamente en la primera línea, ¿quizás que la cadena retornada por `input()` sea tratada como lista? En ese caso: `a=list(input())`.

Comment: El programa que debo hacer es el siguiente: Cree un programa en Python 3 que le solicite al usuario ingresar una lista (mínimo con un elemento), una palabra y un número, luego modificar el primer elemento de la lista con la palabra ingresada y agregar el número al final de la lista. Como resultado el programa mostrará por pantalla la lista la lista modificada. El programa debe mostrar como resultado exclusivamente la lista, no debe contener letras ni enunciados que lo acompañen. Hice lo que me dijeron pero aun asi me da el error "type error"  alguna cosa que me este saltando?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sobre tu código, lo que ingreses en la línea `#1` será registrado como tupla o como string, es por eso que en realidad NO EXISTE el índice que estás usando `a[2]`.

Para comprobarlo puedes imprimir la lista completa:

```
print(a)
```

A su vez también puedes usar:

```
print(a[0])
```

Podrás comprobar que todo lo ingresado por teclado a través de `input()` se guardó solamente en el primer elemento de la lista.

También puedes utilizar un `for` para intentar recorrer los elementos y verificar de acuerdo al número de impresiones en consola la longitud de la lista `a`:

```
for elemento in a:
    print elemento
```

**Edición:**

De acuerdo a tu comentario:

> El programa que debo hacer es el siguiente: Cree un programa en Python 3 que le solicite al usuario ingresar una lista (mínimo con un elemento), una palabra y un número, luego modificar el primer elemento de la lista con la palabra ingresada y agregar el número al final de la lista. Como resultado el programa mostrará por pantalla la lista la lista modificada. El programa debe mostrar como resultado exclusivamente la lista, no debe contener letras ni enunciados que lo acompañen.

El programa sería algo así:

```
lista = list(input("Ingrese una lista: ").split())  # carro, silla, mesa
palabra = input("Ingrese una palabra: ")            # telefono
numero = int(input("Ingrese un numero: "))          # 372

lista[0] = palabra
lista.append(numero)
print(lista) # Debe imprimir ['telefono', 'silla', 'mesa', 372]
```

Lo que se encuentra luego de los `#` son comentarios en Python de cómo debes escribirlos al momento de ingresar los datos a tu programa, adjunto una copia de la salida en línea de comandos del programa para que veas que funciona.

```
Python 3.6.1 (default, Dec 2015, 13:05:11)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux

Ingrese una lista:  casa, auto, telefono
Ingrese una palabra:  celular
Ingrese un numero:  123
['celular', 'auto,', 'telefono', 123]
>>
```

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Pues tenias razon, no lo tomaba como lista, pero ahora he hecho que lo tome como tal y me da type error. en resumen mi programa debe pedirle al usuario ingresar una lista, un string y un entero, luego da como respuesta una nueva lista que seria de la forma lista=[string_ingresado, lista[1], lista[2], entero]. el codigo que envie apenas probaba lo de imprimir lista, pero en este caso, que me sugieres?

Comment: Actualicé mi respuesta con los comentarios proporcionados, eso te servirá como buena referencia para lo que necesites.

Comment: Aclaro que es en python 3 por si las dudas, pues al iglesarlo a  jupyterhub y probarlo con tu codigo y tus ejemplos me manda lo siguiente, que es el mismo error que tengo desde el inicio:       

['"telefono"', 'c', 'a', 'r', 'r', 'o', '"', ',', ' ', '"', 's', 'i', 'l', 'l', 'a', '"', ',', ' ', '"', 'm', 'e', 's', 'a', '"', 372]

no toma la lista como lista, sino mas como string y cada letra ocupa 1 posicion, no cada elemento

Comment: Ya actualicé nuevamente el post para Python 3, incluso puedes ejecutarlo en [este enlace](https://repl.it/repls/TameMobileOpengroup). Suerte! =)

Comment: Si la respuesta fue la acertada, no olvides marcarla como correcta por favor.

Comment: como la marco como correcta, soy nuevo aqui, de hecho, fue acertada

Comment: Justo en la parte superior izquierda de mi respuesta podrás encontrar un Visto (Check), debes presionarlo, eso marca la respuesta como aceptada. `Haz clic en la tacha al lado de la respuesta para cambiarla de gris a color relleno`.

Comment: Ojo con el `.split()`. Si la lista se introduce con las palabras separadas por espacios, entonce bien. Pero si se quiere separar por comas habrá que indicárselo: `.split(",")`

Comment: El enunciado dice que el usuario debe introducir una lista, pero no especifica qué sintaxis debe usar el usuario. Suponiendo que deba usar sintaxis python, es decir, que teclee algo como "[1, 4, 7]", entonces la forma de leerla sería `lista = eval(input())`. Aunque el uso de `eval()` es un riesgo de seguridad (pues ejecuta como python cualquier cosa que el usuario ingrese), es la forma más sencilla de hacer lo que te piden.

Comment: en los comentarios del programa decia que usara la funcion eval, no hay problema porque es un software que evalua, aunque lo del split fue importante, ando en proceso de aprendizaje, ya mismo marco como correcta tu respuesta, gracias. Me pregunto si te puedo contactarpor algun otro medio

Comment: Perfecto, ya está marcada como correcta, si deseas contactarnos por otro medio, puedes hacerlo por [Comunidad de Software Libre y Seguridad Informática - Hackem](https://www.facebook.com/hackem.epn) o por [Python Ecuador](https://www.facebook.com/python.ecuador).